# Testing Django app with Postgis Backend

Tags: python, django, postgresql, unit-testing, postgis

I'm attempting to run tests on a GIS Django application running PostGIS as a database backend.

When I attempt to run tests, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied to create extension "postgis"
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

The error makes sense. Only admin database users can install extensions since this privilege allows the execution of arbitrary external code. BUT since the test runner has to re-create the database each time the tests are run, Django's database user can't proceed.

Here is my database configuration.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'my_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'my_crazy_secure_password',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '',
        'TEST_NAME': 'test_my_db',
    },
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

My solution to this was surprisingly simple, once I figured it out.

Connect to the `template1` database, and run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;`. The `template1` database is copied when a new database is created, so all new databases will already have the extension installed.

Comment: Worked like a charm. You're king.

Comment: Run: `sudo -u postgres psql -d template1 -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;"`